# baxter.urdf not runing, help

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm not sure if it's a Gazebo question, might be a ROS one, but here it goes. I'm following the gazebo tutorials, specifically that one:"Tutorial: Using roslaunch to start Gazebo, world files and URDF models", I've done all what it says until the point that I have to open gazebo with the baxter robot using this command:

rosrun gazebo_ros spawn_model -file `rospack find baxter_description`/urdf/baxter.urdf -urdf -z 1 -model baxter

Well, before that I downloaded the archive and save in my workspace then doing catkin_make, no problems until here. The thing is that when run it this message appears:

[INFO] [1547035629.643023]: Waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model

And after that nothing happens, that's the problem, I've waited for several minutes and nothing. So, I may think that there's something wrong or I've mistaken. Suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21660/baxter.urdf-not-runing,-help/) by [magole](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7633/magole/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I found the answer by myself. https://forum.humanbrainproject.eu/t/waiting-for-service-gazebo-spawn-urdf-model/468
I had to source the setup.bash of ROS first to open Gazebo, then source the setup.bash of my package in an other terminal to spawn the model but now there's a new problem :(.

---

Originally posted by [magole](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7633/magole/) with karma: 1 on 2019-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0